# Magento2 how to remove %2f from URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, magento2

When we are hitting the URL domianname/customer/account/login/%2f we are getting plain page instead of 404 Page without Header and footer

we have try with .htacess by adding

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)((%2F)*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

still showing same result 
also we have try 
Added

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (/.*)\.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error\.php
   RewriteRule . - [R=404,L,NS]
```

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404

is there anything need to be done at server level ? or it can be handle through .htaccess ?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qycvk.png`enter code here`

Comment: That URL does not have a query string, so trying to match %2F in there is pointless.

Comment: _“we are getting plain page”_ - meaning what, exactly? What is the HTTP response code? Perhaps check what [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) is set to first of all, that could have an effect on this.

Comment: once we add AllowEncodedSlashes No on server file it is working as expected now it goes to 404 page thank you @misorude